# It is possible to dynamically change "dragging map option"?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

It is possible to dynamically change "dragging map option"?

I set "dragging: false", but i need to be able to change this option when i click a button.

How can i do that?

Thanks and sorry form my English.

I have tried with invalidateSize() but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaflet includes a class, [`L.Draggable`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#draggable) to make objects draggable. This utility class is added to both markers and the map itself. Both have a property named `dragging` with `enable` and `disable` methods:

```
marker.dragging.disable();
```

The configuration property `dragging` when you create a map instance sets the default state.